# Eensy Weensy etymology?

Tags: etymology

> Eensy weensy spider went up the water spout...

Does *eensy weensy*'s origin precede the rhyme?
What was it used for originally?
Sorry, my Google-fu is badly lacking just now, and I am dying of curiosity.
Anyone know how this weird combination came to be?

Comment: *Little bitty* becomes, via babytalk, *itty-bitty* or, further, *itsy-bitsy*. Thus, the rhyme's form "The itsy-bitsy spider went up the water spout." *Itsy-bitsy* can evolve further to *incy-wincy*, as some people quote the rhyme.

Comment: @MikeGraham - I was thinking it started with Tiny -> Teeny Tiny -> Teeny Weeny -> Teensy Weensy -> Eensy Weensy.

Comment: @Jim Do you expect, then, that the different versions of the rhyme (*itsy-bitsy* vs. *eensy-weensy*) are substitutions of similar phrases rather than an evolution of one phrase? Surely *itsy-bitsy* derives from *little bitty*, right?

Comment: @MikeGraham - Right. I have no data for it, but I think that’s likely. And I agree with you:  little bitty -> itsy bitsy

Comment: I always heard "The itsy bitsy spider went up the water spout.  And, of course, it was an [itsy bitsy teenie weenie yellow polkadot bikini](https://youtu.be/ICkWjdQuK7Q).

Comment: German for 'tiny' is '[winzig](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/winzig)'. Think there's an etymological link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the *OED*, the evolution for "eensy" is in fact, as Jim suggested in the comments:

> *tiny* > *teeny* > *teensy* > *eensy*.

More specifically, the dating laid out in the *OED* offers this ordering for attestations leading up to "eensy weensy."

> *tiny* > *teeny* > *teeny-weeny* > *teensy* > *teensy-weensy* > *eeny-weeny* > *eensy-weensy*

---

**Tiny** dates back to the sixteenth century.  **Teeny** is first attested in the *OED* in 1802 in a quote that compares the two terms.

> The adjective **tiny**, in some provinces **teeny**, is no doubt from this root.

- **1802**   *Monthly Mag.* Dec. 405/1

Meanwhile, Teeny in reduplicated form as "teeny-weeny" appeared attested in 1842.

> Did momor's yettle Dimmy want to put its **teeny-weeny** footseys in the gravy?

- **1842**   *Penny Satirist* 22 Oct. 2/1

**Teensy** appeared in 1856 as a variation of teeny, and is attested in the reduplicated form that preceded "eensy weensy" as **teensy-weensy** in 1872.

> Rose was no longer a funny **teensy-weensy** of an infant pig, but was now a half-grown, solid, fat porker.

- **1872**   *Our Young Folks* July 411

Slightly later than that, and preceding "eensy-weensy," we have our first similar reduplicated variant, "eeny-weeny."

> He [sc. a pet fox] was an **eeny weeny** cunning little red darling.

- **1894**   *Narka (Kansas) News* 7 Sept.

Finally, in 1904, we have our first attestation of "eensy" with "teensy," but the words are separated by a comma and do not appear as an idiomatic reduplication.

> He thought they'd be about six or eight little ducks... There were only two **‘eensy’, ‘weensy’** little ones.

- **1904**   *Churchman* (Hartford, Conn.) 16 July 111/3

1935 offers our first attestation of "eensy weensy" as a reduplication, and it appears hyphenated.

> Not even if they are **eensy-weensy** pieces?

- **1935**   S. Cleugh *Angel who couldn't Sing* xii. 157

Interestingly, the *OED* also offers an outlier variant "eentsy teentsy" appearing in 1914, but this does not appear to have played an etymological role in the formation of "eensy weensy."

> If he discovered one edge protruding even an **eentsy-teentsy** bit beyond the others it would make him unhappy.

- **1914**   *Daily Northwestern* (Oshkosh, Wisconsin) 10 Feb. 6/5